# ¿Como ocultar un elemento html sin que pierda su espacio en la pantalla?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lo que quiero lograr es mantener oculto algunos `labels` ya sea a travez de su `clase` o de su `ID`, lo que estoy tratando de conseguir es un `accordion` de manera dinamica en formato horizontal.

Si yo le doy clic en cualquier `accordion` este deberia de ocultarme todas las pestañas excepto la que se selecciono, esto ya lo realiza a media, porque cuando los `objetos` no seleccionados se ocultan el `accorcdion` cambia de tamaño.

Asi se ve cuando se ocultan los elementos de HTML

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cuando ingreso al sistema asi se ve y asi deberia verse en ese mismo tamaño.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo para ocultar elementos:

```
    function ocultarInfo() {
        $('#textName1').hide();
        $('#textCertificate1').hide();
        $('#textRFC1').hide();
        $('#textType1').hide();
        $('#textCountry1').hide();
        $('#textState1').hide();
        $('#textAdress1').hide();
        $('#textCode1').hide();
        $('#textPhone1').hide();


        $('.textLBL1').hide();
    }
```

Codigo para mostrar los elementos del Accordion seleccionado

```
    function verInfo(conta) {

            if (conta == 2) {
    $('#txtNombre' + conta).show();
    $('#txtCertificado' + conta).show();
    $('#txtRFC' + conta).show();
    $('#txtSistema' + conta).show();
    $('#txtPais' + conta).show();
    $('#txtEstado' + conta).show();
    $('#txtTelefono' + conta).show();
    $('#txtDireccion' + conta).show();
    $('#txtCodigo' + conta).show();

    setTimeout(ocultarInfo, 2000);

}
```

Ya me oculta los elementos solo que cuando lo hace el `accordion` cambia de tamaño y los nuevos elementos que deberian de verse no se ven correctamente.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Utiliza la propiedad `visibility` de css, en vez de los metodos `hide()` y `show()`.

La propiedad visibility se utiliza para determinar si las cajas que genera un elemento son renderizadas.

como ejemplo:

```
function ocultarInfo() {
    $("#textName1").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    // -------
}

function verInfo(conta) {
    // --------
    $('#txtNombre' + conta).css('visibility', 'visible');
    // -------
}
```

http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/visibility

Answer (score -1):

Puedes crear una funcion en tu JavaScript para que te oculte los elementos de tu html

```
 function ocultarInfo(){
   $("#txtNombre").css("display", "none");
   $("#txtCertificado").css("display", "none");
   $("#txtRFC").css("display", "none");
 }
```

y para Mostrar Solo debes:

```
function MostrarInfo(){
   $("#txtNombre").css("display", "block");
   $("#txtCertificado").css("display", "block");
   $("#txtRFC").css("display", "block");
 }
```

Puedes Jugar un poco con tus Div en caso de querer ocultar una region:

```
   <div class="row" id="datos" name="datos" style="display:block;">
   //tu Html
  </div>
```

Comment: utilizar `display:block` también reduciría el tamaño del contenedor, seria bueno solo si el `div` tiene un alto fijo, y vendrían problemas de diseño si en este `div` se agregan elementos dinámicos.